# How to use setup.py to install a python application

Tags: python, wxpython, distutils, setup.py

I am having problems understanding how best to use distutils and setup.py to install my wxPython Python application.

Here are my requirements:

- Installs under Windows, Linux, OS X (is this feasible, or should I be focusing on Linux, and distribute binaries for Windows and OS X?)
- For Linux, installs the main script in /usr/bin/ and removes the .py extension so it can be evoked with `# gooeypi`
- Installs all other files in the python library folder (or a subfolder?) so imports will work.

An additional question: where would the application install under Windows?

Last question: is my tree correct? Should my main executable be in the same folder as my other modules? Would this cause potential name collisions with other modules, especially with common names like util and pref?

Here is my tree:

```
gooeypi\ 
    ----gooeypi\
          ------gooeypy.pyw # main executable
          ------controller.py
          ------util.py 
          ------pref.py
          ------configspec.ini
    ----setup.py
    ----LICENSE
    ----MANIFEST.in
    ----README.txt
```

And my setup.py

```
$ cat setup.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='GooeyPi',
    version='0.1',
    description='Cross-platform wxPython GUI front-end to PyInstaller',
    author='Pedram Navid',
    author_email='pedram.navid at gmail dot com',
    url='http://www.github.com/multiphrenic/GooeyPi',
    packages=['gooeypi'],
    scripts=['gooeypi/gooeypi.pyw'],
     )
```

Comment: in the 2nd folder gooeypi you need the empty file  `__init__.py` so python will understand that gooeypi is a package. Finally to test all of your packaging enter `python setup.py` and see what's going wrong or not

Comment: whoops, missed __init__.py but it is in there. when I run python setup.py install, the installation works, but i am left with a gooeyi.pyw file in /usr/bin when it should be just gooeypi. I've seen this work with other python-apps installed under linux, I just can't recall which ones off the top of my head..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get automatic creation of platform-specific executables, you need to use setuptools on top of distutils: http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation

[Updated Link](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) if the one above isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

the solution about your script is in [the official doc](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts) ;)

but first of all, I think you need to copy your script gooeypi/gooeypi.pyw to gooeypi/gooeypi, then `setup.py` will look like this :

```
setup(name='GooeyPi',
    version='0.1',
    description='Cross-platform wxPython GUI front-end to PyInstaller',
    author='Pedram Navid',
    author_email='pedram.navid at gmail dot com',
    url='http://www.github.com/multiphrenic/GooeyPi',
    packages=['gooeypi'],
    scripts=['gooeypi/gooeypi'],
     )
```

in `MANIFEST.in` put :

```
include gooeypi/gooeypi
```

Comment: hmm, makes sense, but then that eliminates compatibility with Windows no? The more reading I do on this, the more it seems I will need a separate solution for Windows vs Linux platforms..which is fine. I think I will spend some more time poking around at other cross-platform python apps.

Comment: just make a try on windows. Copy the whole set of files and do `python setup.py` too, except if you dont have a computer with this OS.